# Caching videos for webapp - bad idea?

Tags: iphone, html, css, web-applications

I'm creating a webapp for the iPhone. I want to let users offline use the app, but the app also has videos in it. Is it a bad idea to cache those videos?

Thanks in advance,
Renzo

Comment: Save them in persistant storage you will have to take care of DRM and other network pollutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cache manifest have a 5MB limit on iPhone, so yes, it's a bad idea to cache videos